# Changing spinnermodel into a double value to be used later outside change event

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jform-designer

The issue I am running into is changing the SPinnerModel type into a double as it will be used later in the program. Also I cannot use weightSpinnerMetric outside of its method, but I am not sure on how to fix that.

Thanks once again guys.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

public class UI  {

private JSpinner weightSpinnerMetric;

 //Need to change the weightSpinnerMetric to double and then use it here but cannot do either

private void weightSpinnerMetricStateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
JSpinner weightSpinnerMetric = (JSpinner) e.getSource();
SpinnerModel spinnerModel = weightSpinnerMetric.getModel();
System.out.println(spinnerModel.getValue());


weightSpinnerMetric = new JSpinner(); //Spinner created here.

weightSpinnerMetric.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(3, 3, 31, 1));
        weightSpinnerMetric.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                weightSpinnerMetricStateChanged(e);
                weightSpinnerMetricStateChanged(e);
            }
        });
}}
```

As it stands, I wish to call the spinnermodel in another method(A button) so the spinnermodel value is called when the button is pressed, for a visual example I have the following: [image]

Comment: Perhaps it's me, but I find your question confusing. If you don't get a decent answer soon, can you elaborate on it a bit? Like what *exactly* are you trying to do, and how does your current code fail?

Comment: As it stands, I wish to call the spinnermodel in another method(A button) so the spinnermodel value is called when the button is pressed, for a visual example I have the following:  http://i50.tinypic.com/15ejbs.png

Comment: Why not give the class that holds the JSpinner a public method `getWeightSpinnerValue()` and in it return the value held by the weight JSpinner? I'm still confused as to what's holding you back. Please assume that we know nothing about code that you don't show us and that we can't read minds. Not my down-vote by the way.

Comment: @hovercraft-full-of-eels ,Thank you that is exactly what I needed. I apologise for my vagueness and will keep in mind about clarity for future questions

Comment: No problem. Glad you've got it solved. I have up-voted your question and @esej's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the other method is in the same class UI, just call it?
As in:

```
weightSpinnerMetric.getModel().getValue();
```

And if you need it to be a double cast it with `(double)`.

If the method is in another class, you should provide a none-private method in UI similar to this:

```
public double getCurrentWeight() {
    return (double) weightSpinnerMetric.getModel().getVale();
}
```

An alternative approch is to have a variable hold the current input weight, and update it in `weightSpinnerMetricStateChanged` instead of `System.out.println(spinnerModel.getValue())` set that value to that variable.

Comment: Thank you that is exactly what I needed. I apologise for my vagueness and will keep in mind about clarity for future questions.